# css responsive with checkbox

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with checkbox and label. When I re-size screen the label split line, and checkbox should split follow label also.currently, when label stay in new line, but checkbox not stay in the same place of label. What I need is pair new line when responsive.

Anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance for your helping!

Below is my code

```
<div id="score">
    <input type="radio" id="score_0" name="score" required="required" value="1">
    <label for="score_0" class="required">E</label>

    <input type="radio" id="score_1" name="score" required="required" value="2">
    <label for="score_1" class="required">D</label>

    <input type="radio" id="score_2" name="score" required="required" value="3">
   <label for="score_2" class="required">C</label>

   <input type="radio" id="score_3" name="score" required="required" value="4">
   <label for="score_3" class="required">B</label>

   <input type="radio" id="score_4" name="score" required="required" value="5">
   <label for="score_4" class="required">B+</label>

   <input type="radio" id="score_5" name="score" required="required" value="6">
   <label for="score_5" class="required">A</label>

  <input type="radio" id="score_6" name="score" required="required" value="7">
   <label for="score_6" class="required">S</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: Are you not using bootstrap? Or any grid system for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually nest your `inputs` into the label tag, then set a style for the label

```css
.scores label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="scores">
  <label for="score_1" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_1" name="score" required="required" value="2">D</label>
  <label for="score_2" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_2" name="score" required="required" value="3">C</label>
  <label for="score_3" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_3" name="score" required="required" value="4">B</label>
  <label for="score_4" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_4" name="score" required="required" value="5">B+</label>
  <label for="score_5" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_5" name="score" required="required" value="6">A</label>
  <label for="score_6" class="required">
    <input type="radio" id="score_6" name="score" required="required" value="7">S</label>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yaa5ggss/1/) - Easier to resize here